# Как не выводить значения "" и 0, не исключая их из списка?? Python

Tags: python

Есть 2 списка:

```
list = [0, 1, 3, 22]
list2 = ["", "Телевизор", "Стол", "Обои"]
```

Можно ли не выводить значения "" и 0? При этом не исключать их из этих списков

Comment: Так в вопросе вообще вывода нет.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def zero(lst):
       for i in lst:
              if i:
                     print(i)

lst = [0, 1, 3, 22]
lst2 = ["", "Телевизор", "Стол", "Обои"]
zero(lst)
zero(lst2)

1
3
22
Телевизор
Стол
Обои

for x in zip(lst, lst2):
       quantity, item = x
       if quantity:
              print(quantity, item)

1 Телевизор
3 Стол
22 Обои
```

Comment: Это-то совсем просто:-) Я вот задумался, как бы вывести список в виде: [1, 2, 22]? Не пришло сразу ничего в голову. (И `if i` еще и `None` не выведет, например, тогда `if i!=0 and i!=""` более правильно).

Comment: @Сергей Ш, большое спасибо! Можете подсказать, а можно ли вывести их по очереди? То есть, '1 Телевизор, 3 Стол и т.д.'?

Comment: добавил в ответ

Answer (score 1):

Немного разовью тему и предположу, что пустое соответствующее значение в списке наименований имеет не только индекс 0 но и другие индексы

```py
from itertools import compress
ids = [0, 1, 3, 22, 52, 88]
names = ["", "Телевизор", "Стол", "Обои", "", "Стул"]

# Для получения сортированного вывода можно обернуть compress в sorted
# вместо map(bool, names) можно подставить просто names 
# но для наглядности оставлю так
for key, val in compress(zip(ids, names), map(bool, names)):
    print(key, val)

# 1 Телевизор
# 3 Стол
# 22 Обои
# 88 Стул

print(
    ids,
    names,
    sep='\n'
)
# Списки остались не измененнными
# [0, 1, 3, 22, 52, 88]
# ['', 'Телевизор', 'Стол', 'Обои', '', 'Стул']
```

Comment: Ответ тоже подходит! Спасибо большое! Жалко на форуме нельзя выбрать  несколько хороших ответов((